# What package contains "bitset.sty"?

Tags: packages

I am doing a document in latex (texworks), but I am getting the following  error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `bitset.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

Texworks is not able to download it automatically...

Comment: It's in the "oberdiek" package bundle.

Comment: ... and the name of the package is bitset

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TeXworks doesn't do any downloading of missing packages. You're probably relying on MiKTeX's ability to download packages if they aren't yet present on your local system. I don't really know much about this automatic download feature, but it may possibly fail for some package.

Anyway, the `bitset` package is part of the so-called "oberdiek bundle", which includes most of the packages developed and maintained by [Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16967/heiko-oberdiek).

The MiKTeX page for the package is http://miktex.org/packages/oberdiek and the package can be installed with the MiKTeX Package Manager.

On TeX Live distributions, the name is the same and the maneuver for installing it with `tlmgr` is

```
tlmgr install oberdiek
```

It's not recommendable to install it alone, because you would miss updates, so install the whole bundle. As Ryan Reich remarks, most of these Oberdiek's packages rely on other package in the same bundle. It's the case for `bitset` that requires `infwarerr`, `intcalc` and `bigintcalc`; the last one requires `pdftexcmds`, which wants `ltxcmds`, `ifluatex` and `ifpdf`. So, taking care of all these dependencies is longer than downloading the whole set.

If disk space is not a problem for you, I suggest to do a full install of the whole TeX distribution (MiKTeX or TeX Live) and to regularly check for updates.

Comment: Not to mention that the oberdiek packages are often deeply interwritten, so you'd need to install half a dozen utility packages to make it work anyway.

Comment: @RyanReich You're right! `bitset` requires `infwarerr`, `intcalc` and `bigintcalc` from the same bundle.